# Is it possible to reuse the Manage Items functionality in Pages on our own components?

Tags: xm-cloud

The Link List component that ships with XM Cloud + SXA allows you to add and remove links which are just child items on the datasource item. Can we reuse this functionality on our own components, for example an Accordion datasource item which has Accordion Item child datasource items?

The content authors are looking to avoid having to use Content Editor to manage these.

[image: Link List]

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you need to add the `_HorizonDatasourceGrouping` - `{D0F6BE14-2A2D-4C56-ACB5-80CAA573B8E2}` as a Base template to your datasource item template. Then on your datasource item template Standard Values, configure the insert options if you haven't already and assign the child datasource item template.